# How to find arbitrary URLs in plain text?

Tags: regex, url, text, hyperlink, text-parsing

There are tons of solutions to find and/or parse normal URLs, but none of them deals with arbitrary text, i.e. URLs that are split over several lines? How would you find a URL that can have line breaks after any character?

Note: I'm not interested in the individual parts of the URL. I just want to find all URLs in a given text to convert them to links (e.g. like in plain e-mail text).

Example:

```
Text text text text text. Look at this:
http://stackoverfl
ow.com/
questions/15252042/
find-urls-in-text

Question question question.
```

Comment: Yes, please give some example of what you are talking about

Comment: You ask "How would you find a URL that can have line breaks after any character?" and I don't think you have any reliable way to do that.  Sometimes crap data is crap data and you can't do anything with it.

Comment: How do e-mail programs find URLs in plain text? Come on, it's not rocket sience.

Comment: They ignore links like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several approaches are possible:

1) Write a regex with whitespace rules after each regular char. This will certainly blow up the regex pattern but is the most flexible one. For catching line breaks use DOT_ALL mode. DOT_ALL will however produce the same problems as the next approach.

2) (Temporarily) remove line breaks and use normal regex pattern matching. This approach has problems though as it can happen that you include more text than necessary (at the end of the URL) or don't find a URL (if the linebreak is at the start, messing up the protocol string).

2a) A modification of 2) could be to do several match attempts removing only certain line breaks, e.g. after looking for an initial URL part (e.g. www, http etc.). Only possible if recognition time is secondary.

3) Ease your task with domain specific knowlege. For instance if you know where line breaks can occur (or if they occur only at specific positions) then look for these specific cases and solve them first. Then return to the usual regex search.

3a) A variation of 3) could be to look specifically for the protocol and and page extension using a regex with full whitespace rules to find start and stop of an URL. This works obviously only if there's always a protocol/filename_with_extension. Transform the found tokens into regular ones without whitespaces (but include a space before the protocol and after the extension) and then remove all line breaks in the text. Now you can match the URL with a regular regex.

There are certainly more variations possible, but the general idea is the same.